# Using mtcars data to make a summarised table of cylinders versus centered(mpg)

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Bare with me... I am using the **R/RStudio** with the data **mtcars**,  **dplyr** , **mutate** and the **summarise** commands. Also tried **group by**.

I want to center the values *mtcars$mpg* then take that info and display the summary of the number of *cylinders vs centered mtcars$mpg*.

So far...

```
mtcars %>% mutate(centered_mpg = mpg - mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% summarise(centered_mpg, cyl)
```

The above produces:

| centered_mpg | cyl |
| --- | --- |
| 0.909375 | 6 |
| 0.909375 | 6 |
| 2.709375 | 4 |
| 1.309375 | 6 |
| ... | ... |

INSTEAD, I WANT:

| centered_mpg | cyl |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | 4 |
| x2 | 6 |
| x3 | 8 |

Comment: How do you want to summarize the centered `mpg` for each group of cars (for each `cyl` value)? Do you want the mean centered mpg by cyl? Or median, sum, something else? I imagine something like `mtcars %>% mutate(centered_mpg = mpg - mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mean_centered_mpg = mean(centered_mpg))`, but swap out the `mean()` inside `summarize()` for whatever function you'd like.

Comment: I think that's the ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
with(mtcars, aggregate(list(centered_mpg=scale(mpg, scale=FALSE)), list(cyl=cyl), mean))
#   cyl centered_mpg
# 1   4    6.5730114
# 2   6   -0.3477679
# 3   8   -4.9906250
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants `scale(mpg, scale = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to center each individual car's `mpg` by subtracting the global `mean(mpg)`. This gives a `centered_mpg` for every car - and the code you have looks fine for this.

Then you want to calculate some sort of "summary" of the centered mpg values by cylinder group, so we need to `group_by(cyl)` and then define whatever summary function you want - here I use `mean()` but you can use `median`, `sum`, or whatever else you'd like.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(centered_mpg = mpg - mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean_centered_mpg = mean(centered_mpg))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl mean_centered_mpg
#   <dbl>             <dbl>
# 1     4             6.57 
# 2     6            -0.348
# 3     8            -4.99
```